# get onClick event on button tags of HTML set in TextView

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-layout, textview

I would like to know whether there is any way to add onClick event of Android in textview after clicking on the button tag of HTML inside it?
I know it is possible in WebView but please tell me the same for TextView.

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>click on button</h2><br><Button onclick='myClick();'>Description here</Button>"));`

Sample code would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi instead of this, just give click listener to your **textView** and check what they are doing in **myClick();** and you do that action.

Comment: hey, I have to add few input elements and some images as well as buttons in a textView but only button has to be clicked.

Comment: You want to add **few input elements* in webview.?

Comment: yes, it may have some another input tags. but the important thing is that i want to call an onClick listener on clicking on the button of the Webview Object

Comment: @DurgeshSatyam Do you have did it yet? I am looking for answers to similar problem. Please share your solution if you have did it yet

Comment: @Hoa.Tran I am afraid not. The solution I got is just a fix by using 2 or more textViews with one having the only **button** HTML element. I then gave a click listener on that button's **textView** which will impact on the other **textView**s. Which can be controlled by any function by changing the HTML content of the other textViews.
I hope it would solve your problem too. Thanks.